# APC values randomly disappear

Tags: php, apc

I'm using APC for storing a map of class names to class file paths. I build the map like this in my autoload function:

```
$class_paths = apc_fetch('class_paths');

// If the class path is stored in application cache - search finished.

if (isset($class_paths[$class])) {
    return require_once $class_paths[$class];

// Otherwise search in known places

} else {

    // List of places to look for class

    $paths = array(
        '/src/',
        '/modules/',
        '/libs/',
    );

    // Search directories and store path in cache if found.

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        $file = DOC_ROOT . $path . $class . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            echo 'File was found in => ' . $file . '<br />';

            $class_paths[$class] = $file;
            apc_store('class_paths', $class_paths);
            return require_once $file;
        }
    }   
}
```

I can see as more and more classes are loaded, they are added to the map, but at some point the `apc_fetch` returns `NULL` in the middle of a page request, instead of returning the map.

```
Getting => class_paths
Array
(
    [MCS\CMS\Helper\LayoutHelper] => /Users/mbl/Documents/Projects/mcs_ibob/core/trunk/src/MCS/CMS/Helper/LayoutHelper.php
    [MCS\CMS\Model\Spot] => /Users/mbl/Documents/Projects/mcs_ibob/core/trunk/src/MCS/CMS/Model/Spot.php
)
Getting => class_paths
{null}
```

Many times the cached value will also be gone between page requests.

What could be the reason for this?

I'm using APC as an extension (PECL) running PHP 5.3.

**UPDATE:**
In the comments below you will see people stating that APC is not persistent and that it is not to be trusted. But in my case the code is executed in one page request between 15-50ms. Shouldn't I be able to *trust* the APC for that long?

**UPDATE:**
It seems that the cache contains multiple entries with the same key, when it should only contain one - that is overwritten the value when invoking `apc_store()`. I hope this can help someone understand the problem. (I've disabled slam defense and write lock)

```
Array
(
    [num_slots] => 4099
    [ttl] => 0
    [num_hits] => 0
    [num_misses] => 3
    [num_inserts] => 9678
    [expunges] => 0
    [start_time] => 1293109072
    [mem_size] => 40064
    [num_entries] => 8
    [file_upload_progress] => 1
    [memory_type] => mmap
    [locking_type] => file
    [cache_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [info] => fSchema::mysql::fORM::default::/Users/mbl/Documents/Projects/mcs_ibob/core/trunk/public_html/::::column_info
                    [ttl] => 0
                    [type] => user
                    [num_hits] => 0
                    [mtime] => 1293109072
                    [creation_time] => 1293109072
                    [deletion_time] => 0
                    [access_time] => 1293109072
                    [ref_count] => 0
                    [mem_size] => 12456
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [info] => mcs:odk:class_paths
                    [ttl] => 3600
                    [type] => user
                    [num_hits] => 0
                    [mtime] => 1293109072
                    [creation_time] => 1293109072
                    [deletion_time] => 0
                    [access_time] => 1293109072
                    [ref_count] => 0
                    [mem_size] => 648
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [info] => mcs:odk:class_paths
                    [ttl] => 3600
                    [type] => user
                    [num_hits] => 0
                    [mtime] => 1293109072
                    [creation_time] => 1293109072
                    [deletion_time] => 0
                    [access_time] => 1293109072
                    [ref_count] => 0
                    [mem_size] => 648
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [info] => mcs:odk:class_paths
                    [ttl] => 3600
                    [type] => user
                    [num_hits] => 0
                    [mtime] => 1293109072
                    [creation_time] => 1293109072
                    [deletion_time] => 0
                    [access_time] => 1293109072
                    [ref_count] => 0
                    [mem_size] => 648
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [info] => mcs:odk:class_paths
                    [ttl] => 3600
                    [type] => user
                    [num_hits] => 0
                    [mtime] => 1293109072
                    [creation_time] => 1293109072
                    [deletion_time] => 0
                    [access_time] => 1293109072
                    [ref_count] => 0
                    [mem_size] => 648
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [info] => mcs:odk:class_paths
                    [ttl] => 3600
                    [type] => user
                    [num_hits] => 0
                    [mtime] => 1293109072
                    [creation_time] => 1293109072
                    [deletion_time] => 0
                    [access_time] => 1293109072
                    [ref_count] => 0
                    [mem_size] => 648
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [info] => mcs:odk:class_paths
                    [ttl] => 3600
                    [type] => user
                    [num_hits] => 0
                    [mtime] => 1293109072
                    [creation_time] => 1293109072
                    [deletion_time] => 0
                    [access_time] => 1293109072
                    [ref_count] => 0
                    [mem_size] => 648
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [info] => fSchema::mysql::fORM::default::/Users/mbl/Documents/Projects/mcs_ibob/core/trunk/public_html/::::merged_column_info
                    [ttl] => 0
                    [type] => user
                    [num_hits] => 0
                    [mtime] => 1293109072
                    [creation_time] => 1293109072
                    [deletion_time] => 0
                    [access_time] => 1293109072
                    [ref_count] => 0
                    [mem_size] => 23720
                )

        )

    [deleted_list] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: @Michael: maybe because your cache is full so it drops it

Comment: @RageZ: I only storing a few strings. Could be an issue with hitting the `apc_store` to often/fast?

Comment: @Michael: I never used APC but if it's same as memcache they is no warranties that the system will keep your data around forever. So I agree with BarsMonster answer.

Comment: @RageZ but still it we talking about millies between each hit to the class autoload function, APC has to store values longer than that?

Comment: This recent article from Gopal (one of APC's main authors) may shed some not-too-technical light on your problem (intentionally a comment, not an answer): http://phpadvent.org/2010/share-and-enjoy-by-gopal-vijayaraghavan

Comment: i have a problem like that too, cache flushes itself without reaching any kind of limit and/or threshold :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to answer my own question from what I've learned.

Firstly like many people has rightly pointed out.

```
APC is not persistent.
```

It was for me hard to accept this statement without a practical explanation or even better a guide on how to work with it.

I've come to find that there are some rules or rather pitfalls to be aware of - many still eludes me. Using the APC API means using `apc_fetch` and `apc_store` both of these can fail, or as it is more correctly put, miss. And why you sometimes receive `NULL` when you expected data is where the mystery lies.

Here are some random bits of information:

- If you try to store a value before the TTL runs out a new entry will be created. So slow down writing or decrease TTL.

> The number of seconds a cache entry is
>   allowed to idle in a slot in case this
>   cache entry slot is needed by another
>   entry. Leaving this at zero means that
>   APC's cache could potentially fill up
>   with stale entries while newer entries
>   won't be cached. -
>   http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php

- Play around with `apc.ttl` and `apc.user_ttl` till you find something that suits you - until you see lots of hits and not to many entries.
- `apc_fetch` and `apc_store` can return `NULL` for a number of reasons, some hinted above, such as ttl another reason can be a key fetch timeout. But the point is design-around it. Expect this.

If you like me have been feeling very frustated about APC's behaviour have a look at this article pointed out to me by scoates: http://phpadvent.org/2010/share-and-enjoy-by-gopal-vijayaraghavan . It will not give you much answers but some basic knowledge about cache design and perhaps like me some relief in the fact I'm not alone :)

In my case with the class-path issue described in my question, I decided to use a local variable to build up the cache and then at the end storing it in the cache with one single `apc_store` invocation. This brought the hits way up and the cache entries per key way down - and my code is now running fast.

Answer (score 5):

It's not persistent storage.
You may improve it by increasing memory size of APC but anyway, there are no warranties.
So you should reinit values if you see they are dropped.

Comment: To what extend is it not persistent? totally without rules? :)

Comment: Yes, it might purge your records at any moment.

Comment: Uhm, can some one point me to the APC Specification that says "has to randomly delete elements and flush itself for no apparent reason" xD

Comment: Hannes, nobody says that it's random. But APC is not persistent.

Answer (score -2):

APC IS persistent but separate for each apache process.

PHP mentains a separate APC CACHE storage for each apache process, which is perfectly normal because each apache process has his own memory space.

Comment: So the same user will not "hit" the same process between two requests?

Comment: I think you are wrong. APC is a global cache for the local server (no network communication, no access from other servers).

Comment: not when you use CGI. every PHP CGI process has its own apc cache instance.